# Kotlin For Loop with filter only producing 1 result

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm running a `for` `loop` to match `string` entries in a list to entries in a `setOf strings` but it only returns one result when there are multiple matches

```
fun fetchResults() {
    var favelist = preferenceProvider.getStringSet("fave list")
    var episodes = listOf<Episodes>()
    favelist?.let {
        for (item in it) {
            episodes = archiveJSON.filter { it.epAudioURL == item }
        }
    }

    activity?.runOnUiThread {
        recyclerView_ArchiveMain.adapter = ArchiveAdapter(episodes)
    }
}
```

The `faveList` set has 5 matches to the `archiveJSON` but only displays 1

Comment: So you override episodes list on each loop. You should add (.addAll).

Comment: Great! That works, thanks. Do you want to add it as an answer so i can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you override episodes list on each loop. You should add (.addAll).